# Trying to static link a cygwin compiled program using either gcc or mingc with issues

Tags: gcc, cygwin, mingw

I have a sizable program, multiple Mb, that compiles and runs fine using gcc and `cygwin1.dll`, but I cannot figure out how to statically compile it so that I can distribute it without `cygwin1.dll`, which is always in the dependency list.

This is allegedly supposed to work, but I cannot figure out why it does not. I'm on gcc 11.4.0 with a Cygwin updated about a week ago. The reason I need this is to use the LGPL Cygwin licensing.

Does anyone have any pointers on the correct way to do this?

When building with mingw, the program has no warnings but get a `sigsegv` in `msvcrt!_lock` any time I use `printf`, even with the most trivial format in the first line of the main program. A trivial hello world program works using mingw but that's about all - anything complex has the `sigsegv`. If feels like I am not linking in the proper root main program for windows - I am not specifying one on the link line other than the object with my own main().

When I use mingw, I end up failing with an access to memory `0x0` in `ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk()`.

My gcc attempts have included using `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static` and explicitly referencing `/usr/lib/libcygwin.a`.

Comment: why you can distribuite with the cygwin1.dll ? Building for cygwin is NOT designed for static link to the groundbase dll.

Comment: Distributing cygwin1.dll causes the full GPLv3 license provisions to take effect and would thus requires us to disclose our intellectual property including source code to the public. By static linking with libcygwin.a (according to CygWin), we only invoke the LGPL, which allows us to keep our source code private. The LGPL provision is discussed on the cygwin website but instructions on doing this are incompletely.

Comment: compiling static with Cygwin make no differences for that License issue. However the document at  `/usr/share/doc/Cygwin/CYGWIN_LICENSE` should cover your worriies

Comment: @matzeri I am sorry to disagree, but there is a difference between dynamic and static linking. This is stated in that file as
```
Linking Exception:

  As a special exception, the copyright holders of the Cygwin library
  grant you additional permission to link libcygwin.a, crt0.o, and
  gcrt0.o with independent modules to produce an executable, and to
  convey the resulting executable under terms of your choice, without
  any need to comply with the conditions of LGPLv3 section 4. An
  independent module is a module which is not itself based on the
  Cygwin library.
```

Comment: Stack size issue ? Have you tried something like -Wl,--stack,8388608 ?

Comment: Will give that a try. I have tried memory model changes without success.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin is a way of building with GCC for Windows using a compatibility layer, which is in `cygwin1.dll`.

What you need to do is build *native* Windows binaries, using MinGW-w64.

You can get it by installing [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) and installing MinGW-w64 using its package manager `pacman`.

Or if you don't need the *nix shell you can get a standalone MinGW-w64 build from https://winlibs.com/

Comment: I am specifically trying to use the cygwin compatibility layer contained in libcygwin.a and gcrt0.o rather than hand-coding for windows as in the original question.

Comment: If you stay away from certain non-portable things like `fork()` it's not that much work to write portable code that runs natively on Windows. For networking stuff the headers are different (`#include <winsock2.h>`) but most of the code doesn't need modification.